# Rspec for begin ... rescue block in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am writing a test which should verify that when the object creation saves, indeed the exception is caught.

```
begin
  object.create!(item)
rescue => exception
  exception.message
end
```

rspec

```
 expect{ exception.message }.to eq("Validation failed: Item name can't be blank")
```

output I got:

```
 Failure/Error: expect{ exception.message }.to eq("Validation failed: Item name can't be blank")
       You must pass an argument rather than a block to `expect` to use the provided matcher (eq "Validation failed: Item name can't be blank"), or the matcher must implement `supports_block_expectations?`.
```

Can anyone help  me out?

Comment: error message says you need to pass `exception.message` as parameter not block. so replace curly brackets with normal ones and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test your code like that because the `exception` variable only exists in the `rescue` block. Instead, you need to call the method you want to test and add an expectation of what it should return.

Your example actually doesn't have such a method that could be called. I imagine that your method actually looks like this:

```
def do_stuff_with(object, item) 
  begin
    object.create!(item)
  rescue => exception
    exception.message
  end
end
```

Then you should be able to have an expectation like this:

```
expect(do_stuff_with(object, item)).to eq(
  "Validation failed: Item name can't be blank"
)
```